# .Net webアプリケーションでアクセス拒否のIPアドレスからのアクセスを403エラーに統一したい。

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, windows-server

初めて質問させていただきます。

.netでWebアプリケーションを開発し、Webサーバに構築して稼働させています。
最近、海外からのアクセスを拒否するべくIISの「IPアドレスとドメインの制限」機能で
日本国内以外のIPアドレスからのアクセスを拒否するように設定しました。
ただ、海外IPからのアクセスでリクエスト不正(400エラー)やリダイレクト(302エラー)となるような
アクセスがあった場合に403エラーにならずに、上記のエラーで返している場合があります。
国内以外のIPアドレスからのアクセスをすべて即拒否になるように、
403エラーで統一したいのですが。。。

ご教授いただける方、よろしくお願いいたします。

サーバー：WindowsServer2022
IISバージョン：10.0
.net Framework 4.8.1

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite Module の使用は検討されたでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご投稿ありがとうございます。確認が遅くなり申し訳ございません。

Comment: URL Rewrite で可能かもしれないのは盲点でした。ただ、国外の複数のIPアドレスを３段目のPatternに設定することになると思われますが、数百パターンになるIPアドレスをここに指定可能なのか不安です。少し試してみます。

Comment: URL Rewrite Module でダメなら「リクエスト不正(400エラー)やリダイレクト(302エラー)となる」のはどういう場合を具体的に書いていただけると、別の案が出てくるかもしれません。その際、Web アプリケーションが何なのか (Web Forms? MVC? Web Page? その他?) も書いてください。

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2022 が手元にないので確認しておりませんが、[セキュリティが強化された Windows Defender ファイアウォール] を利用することはできないでしょうか？
以下は、Windows クライアントの画面ですが、カスタム規則のスコープで IP での制限ができます。
[image: セキュリティが強化された Windows Defender ファイアウォール]

こちらでは、要件を満たすことはできないでしょうか？
やはり、IIS レベルでの IP 制限が必要でしょうか？

Comment: ご投稿ありがとうございます。確認が遅くなり申し訳ございません。ファイアウォールで行う場合、「ステップ：プログラム」の箇所はこの場合はどれを選択する事が妥当なんでしょう。また、他のご投稿のコメントにも記載しましたが、数百パターンとなる国外IPアドレス指定をここに設定可能かどうかも検証ですね。（負荷等も含めて）

Comment: 今回使用する Windows Server 2022 は、他の用途にも使用しているというでしょうか？今回の用途のみであれば、[すべてのプログラム] を選択するので良いかと思います。